# How can I convert character encoding of Chameleon simulator to 'Utf-8' which is default 'latin-1'?

Tags: utf-8, hl7

I want to simulate japanese HL7 message over chameleon simulator. But when I select that message from file, japanese characters are being displayed as special characters into Chameleon simulator. I want it to be displayed as japanese characters.

How can I convert character encoding of Chameleon simulator to 'Utf-8' which is default 'latin-1'?

Comment: Define the charsets explicitly in chameleon.

Answer (score 1):

before receive message, try this:

```
ChameleonEncoding.SetCurrentTranslationLocale("utf-8");  // Tell Chameleon to use current Chameleon Locale
```

Or you can just use local locale:

```
 _currentLocale = ChameleonEncoding.GetCurrentTranslationLocale();   // Get the current Chameleon Locale
 ChameleonEncoding.SetCurrentTranslationLocale(_currentLocale);      // Tell Chameleon to use current Chameleon Locale
```